# What's the different between linkedSetOf and hashSetOf?

Tags: kotlin, collections

In the Kotlin collection functions, we have
`setOf`, `mutableSetOf`, `sortedSetOf`, `linkedSetOf` and `hashSetOf`.

The first 3 is understood their differences. But what's the last two? 
How are they different from others and from themselves?

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear on the differences: [`linkedSetOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/linked-set-of.html) and [`hashSetOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-set-of.html). They both return a hash-based set but the former maintains insertion order.

Comment: Yes, it mentioned the orders is maintained. Perhaps I don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know that `linkedSetOf` returns a `LinkedHashSet` whereas `hashSetOf` returns a `HashSet`. The difference between `LinkedHashSet` and `HashSet` is that `LinkedHashSet` maintains the order of elements with which they were either inserted into or removed from the set whereas `HashSet` doesn't maintain the order.

Observe the example below ([Kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/CQGFClZpo), if you want to see it in action)

```
val set: LinkedHashSet<Int> = linkedSetOf(1, 3, 2)

println(set) // [1, 3, 2]

set.remove(3)
set += listOf(5, 4)
println(set) // [1, 2, 5, 4]

val hashSet: HashSet<Int> = hashSetOf(1, 3, 2)

println(hashSet) // [1, 2, 3]

hashSet.remove(3)
hashSet += listOf(5, 4)
println(hashSet) // [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

If you look at how the set is printed in different instances of addition and removal of elements, you would see that in the case of `LinkedHashSet`, **the order in which the elements were added or removed is maintained** and printed in the same order when iterated over.

**Note:** Just to show that `HashSet` doesn't *sort* the elements, below is an example ([Kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/J7L8WRhfE))

```
val linkedHashSet = linkedSetOf("aaa","bbb","ccc")

println(linkedHashSet) // [aaa, bbb, ccc]

linkedHashSet.remove("ccc")
linkedHashSet += listOf("ddd","zzz")
println(linkedHashSet) // [aaa, bbb, ddd, zzz]


val hashSet = hashSetOf("aaa","bbb","ccc")

println(hashSet) // [aaa, ccc, bbb]

hashSet.remove("ccc")
hashSet += listOf("ddd","zzz")
println(hashSet) // [aaa, bbb, zzz, ddd]
```

Comment: Thanks, upvote for you. Good example. Looks like 'HasSet` is sorting it accordingly. In this case, how is `HashSet` differ from `sortedMapOf()` (or `TreeSet`)?

Comment: @Elye "Looks like `HashSet` is sorting it accordingly" – a `HashSet` has no order. Any perceived order is merely coincidental and cannot be relied upon. As you add and/or remove elements the order can completely change. This is different from `LinkedHashSet` where the order is _always_ the insertion order (i.e. the order the elements were added). A `SortedSet` has an order defined by a `Comparator` and maintains that order as elements are added and/or removed.

Comment: Yes as @Slaw mentioned, hashSet doesn't sort it. I'll add an example to show that.

Comment: @Elye and `sortedMapOf` returns a map which maintains a sorted ordering of its keys either by its natural ordering or by the provided comparator. `TreeSet` is a set implementation using `TreeMap` and also has the ordering by it's elements (or by the provided comparator)

Comment: Nice one. I'll tick your answer, as it provided all the gist. Just wonder what did `hashMap` use to decide its order, as it does seem to preserve some order... if you could elaborate that would be great!

Comment: The answer currently talks about the order in which elements were added _or removed_, but isn't it only the order they were added (that is, for elements which have been removed, the order in which they have been removed makes no difference, as they're not in the set anyway, and if they're ever re-added then it's when they're re-added that matters, and still not when they were removed)?

Answer (score 1):

`linkedSetOf` returns a  `LinkedHasSet`

`hasSetOf` returns a `HashSet`

The main difference between HashSet and LinkedHasSet is that LinkedHasSet maintains insertion order (order in which elements are inserted into LinkedHashSet). On the other hand HashSet doesn't maintain any order.